# Sort forum topics by messages date relationship in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, relationship

I'm using cakephp 2 framework.

I have a model "topic" with a "hasmany" relationship:

```
public $hasMany=array(
                    'Messages' => array(
                                        'className' => 'Messages',
                                        'foreignKey'=>'id_topic',
                                        'dependent'=>true,
                                    ),

                    );
```

In my controller I do:

```
$this->paginate = array(
                    'Topic'    => array(
                            'limit'    => 10,
                            'recursive' => 2,

                        )
                );

$entities = $this->paginate('Topic');
```

It works perfectly but now I would like to sort my topics by date of last message but I don't find how.

Something like:

```
$this->paginate = array(
                    'Topic'    => array(
                            'limit'    => 10,
                            'recursive' => 2,
                            'order'=>'Messages.created desc'

                        )
                );
```

But I get `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Messages.created' in 'order clause'`

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: have you tried this`'order' => array('Messages.created' => 'desc')`

Answer (score 0):

okay now i am showing working code for me, may be it can help you

```
$this->Topic->find('all');
        $this->paginate = array(
                            //'conditions' => array('id !=' => '6'),
                            'limit' => 6,
                            'order' => array('Topic.modified' => 'desc')
                            );
    $data = $this->paginate('Topic');
```

in my case i have model `Topic`, field `modified` in my `topics` table

Comment: I would like to sort by date of the last message on topic not date of the topic ;)
but thanks to help me

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I add a column in my topics table "last_message_date"

```
$this->paginate = array(
                    'Topic'    => array(
                            'limit'    => 10,
                            'recursive' => 2,  
                           'order'=>array('last_message_date'=>'desc')
                        )
                );
```

Not really a proper solution but I've no idea